# Irreducibility for boolean ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, boolean-ring

Every element in $x \in A$ in a commutative bolean ring $A$ is by definition equal to $xx$, and so therefore there are no irreducible elements in the usual sense.  So I ask, how might one define irreducibility for boolean rings?

For instance, a non-unit $x \in A$ is is irreducible if it can't be written $xz$ for any $z \neq x, z \in A$ a non-unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In domains, irreducibility of $x$ corresponds to $(x)$ being maximal in the poset of proper principal ideals.

So, you could use that as the definition.

Comment: Thanks!  Note that every ideal in a boolean ring is principal, i.e. $(x,y) = (x + y + xy)$ so it's actually maximal ideal.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond No, they *aren’t* principal ideal rings.  I pointed out this mistake in the comments to your other question.

Comment: @rschweib saw your comment and proved that you're misinterpreting something that I wrote.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond you wrote “note that every ideal in a Boolean ring is principal.”  I don’t see what I misrepresented.  This assertion is not true in general.

Comment: "Every finitely generated ideal of a Boolean ring is principal (indeed, (x,y)=(x+y+xy))."  My large ring $A$ is generated by the finite monoid $X$.

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond like I said in the same comment “I know you are only interested infinite rings but it’s not good to omit it “(finite generation). It could have easily mislead anyone who read the unqualified statement for Boolean rings.